# Setting up HTTPS for Elastic Beanstalk single instance Python (FastAPI) application

Tags: python, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, fastapi

Please note: No Load Balancers. I'm specifically looking for solutions with single instances.

Greetings! As the title suggests, I'm having trouble setting up HTTPS with a self signed certificate (certbot) for an EB instance running python.

To get started, I did follow the instructions here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/https-singleinstance-python.html, replacing `server.crt` with `cert.pem` and `server.key` with `privkey.pem` generated by certbot, and `application.py` with `asgi.py` (the entry point to my application). All of these in `https-instance.config` and `https-instance-single.config` under `.ebextensions`.

I will include the files here in case I misconfigured something.

> https-instance.config

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod24_ssl: []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
      WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
      WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
      WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        
        Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
        <Directory /opt/python/current/app/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/asgi.py
        
        <Directory /opt/python/current/app>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
        
        WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-ssl processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
          python-path=/opt/python/current/app \
          python-home=/opt/python/run/venv \
          home=/opt/python/current/app \
          user=wsgi \
          group=wsgi
        WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-ssl
        
      </VirtualHost>

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
      -----END PRIVATE KEY-----

container_commands:
  01killhttpd:
    command: "killall httpd"
  02waitforhttpddeath:
    command: "sleep 3"
```

> https-instance-single.config

```
Resources:
  sslSecurityGroupIngress:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroupIngress
    Properties:
      GroupId: { "Fn::GetAtt": ["AWSEBSecurityGroup", "GroupId"] }
      IpProtocol: tcp
      ToPort: 443
      FromPort: 443
      CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Upon deploying, I get `Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'.` with no further details as to what went wrong.

As for the configuration, the proxy server is Apache, WSGIPath `asgi.py`, the rest default.

Edit:

After building a cople of times and reviewing the logs under `eb-engine.log`, ended up with this `https-instance.config`:

```
packages:
  yum:
    mod_ssl: []

files:
  /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so
      WSGIPythonHome /opt/python/run/baselinenv
      WSGISocketPrefix run/wsgi
      WSGIRestrictEmbedded On
      Listen 443
      <VirtualHost *:443>
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt"
        SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key"
        
        Alias /static/ /opt/python/current/app/static/
        <Directory /opt/python/current/app/static>
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        </Directory>
        
        WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/python/current/app/asgi.py
        
        <Directory /opt/python/current/app>
        Require all granted
        </Directory>
        
        WSGIDaemonProcess wsgi-ssl processes=1 threads=15 display-name=%{GROUP} \
          python-path=/opt/python/current/app \
          python-home=/opt/python/run/venv \
          home=/opt/python/current/app \
          user=daemon \
          group=daemon
        WSGIProcessGroup wsgi-ssl
        
      </VirtualHost>

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.crt:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
      -----END CERTIFICATE-----

  /etc/pki/tls/certs/server.key:
    mode: "000400"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
      -----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

The deployment is successful using this, however I still get a `refused to connect` response.

Any suggestions are welcome, thanks in advance!

Comment: do you have any log output as to why the deployment failed

Comment: Please login to your EB instance and check `/var/logs`. EB produces lots of log files. Inspect them all looking for exact error messages.

Comment: @Marcin the `logs` folder under `var` does not exist. Upon inspecting logs `eb-engine.log` it seems like `mod24_ssl` is not installable in the apache version EB installs. Made the appropriate change. On the next build found WSGIDaemonProcess has a bad name and group, so renamed those to `daemon` according to some SO answers. Interestingly, the build was successful, but I still get a `refused to connect` response. Problem is now, no logs to find what failed.

Comment: @Mark Off course it exists. Please check. Maybe its called `log`, not `logs`.

Comment: Wrote that off the top of my head, so forgot to mention it's actually called `log`. That's where I got `eb-engine.log` from anyway.